# Building Debian binary packages with netbeans 6.91

Tags: c++, netbeans, ubuntu, debian, packaging

I am using netbeans to build a set of Debian binary packages on Ubuntu 10.0.4

I am on a 64bit OS, yet the default architecture is 'x386' which results in the following error, when I try to install the package on another 64 bit machine:

Error: Wrong architecture 'i386'

My first question is:

**Question 1.**

What string should I use to indicate that the required architecture is for a 64bit Intel machine?

My second question relates to the dependency between the packages:

I have three (C/C++) projects:

- foo
- foobar
- foofoobar

foobar depends on foo (a shared library), and likewise foofoobar (an application), depends on foobar(another shared library).

**Question 2**

My question in terms of deployment is that:

Do I create a SINGLE Debian package for foofoobar and simply add the shared libraries created in foo and foobar to the Debian package for foofoobar?

**Question 3**

last but not the least, both foo and foobar have third party dependencies (e.g. BOOST shared libraries). Common sense tells me that I need to add ALL the shared libraries files required by foo, foobar and foobar into the foofoobar Debian package - in order to create a stand alone package that can be successfully deployed to another machine that does not have the required libraries.

Is my understanding regarding the external library dependencies correct?

Comment: Regarding Question 1, I just checked some of the binary packages on my system and the string used appears to be amd64 - still, I'd like some confirmation if this is a valid assumption to be made from my casual observation ...

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** The string that indicates a 64bit X86 based architecture is: amd64

**2.)** Depends on your project structure. You can add s much files as you want. But it normally makes sense, to keep different programs in different packages.

**3.)** Yes, you have to include all dependencies directly, if you want to deploy your program at once. Make sure to not plan in directories that may already populated with the files you want to dd on some machines, because otherwise, you cannot install the package without --force. More usual: define some packages, your program requires as dependencies of your package(s) and the package manager will take care of this problem once and for all.